# Facebook android api v4.0 callback is working wrongly

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I am using Android Facebook API 4.0. When I click the cancel button on share window, `onSuccess()` function is triggered but `onCancel()` should be triggered. Is this a bug? Please help me find a solution.

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
ShareDialog shareDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() { 

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(){
            // this function is calling when I Click cancel button
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(){
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(){
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post some code, it will help us better understand your problem.

Comment: This is by design. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#onsuccess